# Event log in a script

Tags: powershell, scripting, event-log

Sending data from event log to a mail message output as `System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntry`

```
$event = Get-EventLog -LogName System -Source "Service Control Manager" -Newest 15 | Format-Table -AutoSize

send-mailmessage -to "email@gmail.com" -from "script@gmail.com" -body "$event" -subject "Script log"
```

output: `System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntry` (x 15)

I am trying to set a script that will send me an email with the last 15 logs from the event log for a different script.

Comment: You need to convert the current output (an object) to a string, or a format in which you can attach or embed in to the email. For example, you could export the event log to csv ($event | export-csv -path c:\temp\log.csv) and add as an attachment to the send-mailmessage cmdlet (-attachment "c:\temp\log.csv")

Comment: I tried using the export-csv command, but it still exports the output as an PS object instead of the actual data.

Comment: Make sure you omit the `| format-table -autosize` from the first line, and if required replace it with a `select` and specify the columns/data you want to export.